# Android dynamic feature of installing

Tags: android

i want to have a feature like hike in my app. Hike consist of a new game feature in which you download the game dynamically and without installing it u can play that game.
plz help me how to add such a feature in my app also.

Comment: post what you have done so far. minimum verifiable example

Comment: to be honest i have implemented nothing. I can tell u  the problem statement but..Statement : we are trying to test the ways to leak the private information from android device (as our major project). now i m finding a way so that at first the app which u install has nothing malware in it. then after some time when some buttons are clicked it request the sever to send some malware code..that malware code wil then leak the information and then delete the code itself(deletion part is not important).. This is our problem statement :) I some how related this type of thing with hike new game featur